# continuity of $f(z)=(z-i)\log(z^2+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> I am trying to determine where $f(z)=(z-i)\log(z^2+1)$ is continuous.

My attempt:

Well, $z-i$ is a complex polynomial, so it is continuous in all of $\mathbb{C}$. Hence, the continuity of $f(z)$ is dependent on $\log(z^2+1)$. I know that $\log(w)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$\ $(-\infty,0]$, so i figured that $\log(z^2+1)$ is continuous when $z^2+1>0$. So,
\begin{align}
z^2+1&>0 \\
x^2-y^2+2xyi&>-1 \\
\end{align}
Equating real and imaginary, $$x^2-y^2>-1 \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ xy=0$$
There are two cases to consider.

Case 1: $$x^2-y^2>-1 \ ,\ x=0$$
this yields $-1<y<1$.

Case 2: $$x^2-y^2>-1 \ ,\ y=0$$
this yields the empty set.

But the answer is for $y\geq 1, y\leq -1$. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for continuity is not $z^2+1>0$. The correct condition (with the chosen branch of the logarithm) is $z^2+1\notin(-\infty,0]$ (you will have to give a special look to $z=i$.)

Comment: Does this condition imply that $\Re(z^2+1)\leq 0$ and $\Im(z^2+1)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that is the discontinuity set. However,have a closer look at $z=i$

Comment: the function is discontinuous at $z=i$ (as this would yield $\log(0)$)?

Comment: But $\lim_{z\to i}f(z)=0$

Comment: Ah crap, so it is continuous at $z=\pm i$.

Comment: @Bell Is it continuous at $-i$?

Comment: In principle it is undefined at $z=i$, but defining $f(i)=0$, it becomes continuous at $z=i$. It is discontinuous at $z=-i$.